# How to test Gmail Contextual Gadget

Tags: gmail, google-apps-marketplace, gmail-contextual-gadgets

I'm new at developing of Gmail Contextual Gadget, and I want just test my gadget, but I can't find how to do that. As I understand I need to have domain at Google Apps and lot more things, Is there any other solution ? And can I add my contextual gadget to regular gmail account, or I need something else ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes - you are going to need a business account.  Your standard Gmail Account won't allow for Contextual Gadgets.

You can pay to get access for 1 user for a year.  You can then use that for your testing.

You will need to have a domain to associate with your account but you can pick one of those up at say godaddy for a few dollars.

Although it sounds like a hassle, if you follow the setup steps and are willing to pay the small cost it won't take too long.

Comment: Thanks for answer. But then, I need to publish my gadget, so every regular user can use it, is it possible, or they need to have domain and etc. for using it ?

Comment: They will need to have a domain to use gadgets.  A better approach for you might be to create a Chrome Extension.  You can manipulate the DOM of Gmail and create a "gadget-like" experience.  We have done this for users that cannot install a gadget.

Comment: The idea of extension is good, and we think of it in first, but it's only for Chrome, and the other browsers doesn't support it, and even if the browser have extensions like FireFox, I need to copy whole logic to FireFox Add-On and it is not so good, and the contextual gadget is the best solution for this problem, I need to parse email and find phone numbers, have you any other suggestion besides this two ?

Comment: Sorry - thats all that I've come across.